# Operating system not found after shut down

Tags: boot, system

I recently broke my Harddrive, so i'd put a new one in and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it through LiveUSB, but the PC could not find the Operating system.

I have a Acer eMachines e640, with amd64 processor.

So I did some research here and found out that I should install GRUB and MBR, so I did by installing the boot-repair. i ran the application and rebooted. Now here's my problem, the first time booting up worked, booting me up to ubuntu, but then I shut down the PC later to see that same  Operating system not found message.

I am here asking for what could be the problem?

Comment: Is there more than one drive in the computer?  Do you have a usb key plugged in?  Either of these can cause drive order to change and make the BIOS or Grub look in the wrong location.

Comment: There is only one drive and the usb is unplugged

Comment: my only other guess is a loose connection to the HDD or a bad HDD controller.

Comment: No, the HDD is fully accessible during LiveUSB, and able to store data on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to improper boot order.

- Get to BIOS, find the boot order menu
- Give top priority to your harddisk. Optionally, disable all other bootable media listed there.

This should fix your problem. If it doesnt, come back to BIOS again to see if the boot order remains exactly the same as you saved previously. If not, then you *may be* screwed.

Comment: HDD is on the top priority

Comment: In that case, there are a variety of options to check for - including how you installed it. Instead of trying the **boot repair**, this time use a live media and `chroot` into your ubuntu installation - chroot is important. Install grub again on `MBR`,ie, on the `sda`, (not `sda1` or something).

Comment: For more info on chroot, https://blog.mister-muffin.de/2011/09/12/restoring-grub-from-live-cd/